# Making multiple filters in function filter() (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

What I want to do is to have multiple values to filter out the data.
I want to have ResourcePost objects with `resource_category` with values of `user.helpseekerprofile.rc1` `user.helpseekerprofile.rc2` and `user.helpseekerprofile.rc3`.
So I tried like below:

```
def message_list_view(request):
    user = request.user

    def filter_watchlist(post):
        filtered = ResourcePost.objects.all().filter(resource_category=user.helpseekerprofile.rc_1)\
             + ResourcePost.objects.all().filter(resource_category=user.helpseekerprofile.rc_2)\
                  + ResourcePost.objects.all().filter(resource_category=user.helpseekerprofile.rc_3)
        if post in filtered:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    post_list = ResourcePost.objects.all().filter(filter_watchlist).order_by("-date_created")

    page = request.GET.get("page", 1)
    paginator = Paginator(post_list, 20)
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    timestamp_now = datetime.datetime.now()
    context = {
        "mapbox_access_token": "pk." + os.environ.get("MAPBOX_KEY"),
        "timestamp": timestamp_now,
        "posts": posts,
    }
    return render(request, "donation/messages_home.html", context)
```

However, `TypeError` came out saying "cannot unpack non-iterable function object".
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a queryset by filtering with:

```
helper = user.helpseekerprofile

post_list = ResourcePost.objects.filter(
    resource_category__in=[helper.rc_1, helper.rc_2, helper.rc_3]
).order_by('-date_created')
```

You can not filter by a generic function like:

```
ResourcePost.objects.filter(filter_watchlist).order_by('-date_created')
```

since the queries are performed at the database side, and one can not convert a function into a query.